# sprite jitter when max acceleration reached at camera

Tags: xna, sprites, monogame

[image]Camera seems making sprite jitter when max acceleration is reached :

Thats my camera code :

```
            var delta = (float)time.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds * 10;
            var speed = (player.recCamPosition().X - _pos.X) / FocusSpeed;
            _pos.X += speed * delta;
            var speedY = (player.GetPosition.Y - 120 - _pos.Y) / FocusSpeed;
            _pos.Y += speedY * delta;
            Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-_pos.X, -_pos.Y, 0));
```

and here my player physic code :

```
     if (TileColission(new Vector2(position.X, position.Y +velocity.Y), map, 1))//&& velocity.Y>0
        {
            if (velocity.Y > 0)
            {
                //    Rectangle t = TileColission2(new Vector2(position.X, position.Y + velocity.Y), map);
                //    position.Y = t.Y-16;
                while (!TileColission(new Vector2(position.X, position.Y + 1), map, 1))
                {
                    position.Y += 1;
                }
                StandingOnGround = true;
            }
            velocity.Y = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            position.Y += velocity.Y;
            StandingOnGround = false;
        }
        if (TileColission(new Vector2(position.X+velocity.X, position.Y ), map, 1))
        {
            velocity.X = 0;
        }
        else
        {

            position.X += velocity.X;
        }
```

all my sprites are round to (int) at his respective drawings methods.

is not very appreciable at gyazo idk why. but the player viber when its moving.
thx for read .

Comment: monogame (XNA) c# adding it

Comment: i did it allready :)

Comment: Could you upload the image to the stack's imgur account (by using the 'Image' tool from the edit tool bar)? That would make sure that the image is always available (in case gayzo decides to remove the image).

Comment: @Alexandre Vaillancourt or upload it at imgur.com and tell us the link ;) , anyway imgur still can decide to remove the pic or not :P

Comment: @user6668201 No, not exactly; stack.imgur is covered by a special contract between stack exchange and imgur, the content will not be removed as long as stack exchange exists. It's different from the 'normal' imgur service.

Comment: done upload at stack.imgur .

Comment: Tried adding f like this? var delta = (float)time.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds * 10f;

Comment: my velocity is working on floats and i just draw it at int at his respective drawing method.